# gridview row count returns 0

Tags: c#, gridview

I have an aspx page with C# in code behind.

In this page, there are 3 gridviews and a button - export to excel.

On button click, the contents of 3 gridviews will be exported to 3 excel sheets.

The data binding of the gridviews are done in a class file and the gridview is returned.

```
string sql1="something1";
classFile.gvBind(gv1,sql1);

string sql2="something2";
classFile.gvBind(gv2,sql2);

string sql3="something3";
classFile.gvBind(gv3,sql3);
```

And it works good. Now on button click, I am looping through the columns and rows of gridviews and exporting them. But always the row count of all gridviews is showing zero. The column headers however are working.

Here is the code on button click:

```
XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
GridView[] gvExcel = new GridView[] { gv1, gv2, gv3};
string[] name = new string[] { "sheetName1", "sheetName2", "sheetName3"};
        for (int i = 0; i < gvExcel.Length; i++)
        {
            if (gvExcel[i].Visible)
            {
                gvExcel[i].AllowPaging = false;
                gvExcel[i].DataBind();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable(name[i].ToString());
                for (int z = 0; z < gvExcel[i].Columns.Count; z++)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(gvExcel[i].Columns[z].HeaderText);
                }


                int x = gvExcel[i].Rows.Count;
                foreach (GridViewRow row in gvExcel[i].Rows)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add();
                    for (int c = 0; c < gvRow.Cells.Count; c++)
                    {
                        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][c] = gvRow.Cells[c].Text;
                    }
                }

                wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
                gvExcel[i].AllowPaging = true;
            }
```

The int x is always =0. Where am I doing wrong? Any help?
Thank you.!!

Comment: you could have directly add the source to Datatable before binding to the grid and cast your grid view datasource as Datatable and use that instead of complicating this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem. I commented out this line

> gvExcel[i].DataBind();

and the row count is coming proper now.
I guess since the dataset and data binding is not executing in this page but from a different .cs file, so when I bind the data again to gridview, its basically null dataset getting bind and rowcnt is also=0.

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach loop body is never entered, since  `gvExcel[i].Rows` is an empty list

so the row is never added

Comment: yes, of course. But why? The gridview has rows and they are showing on executing queries.